# How to detect changes in a prefilled Angular Reactive Form in Edit Mode

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, angular-reactive-forms

I want to detect changes on a Reactive Form while working in Edit Mode.
I tried using valueChanges but the issue is when I am loading an already submitted form for editing it, it is triggering events for each prefilled control.
While my requirement is to only trigger when user made any changes to the form.
Anyone can please suggest

Comment: Try to activate the valueChanges part using some flags while starting the edit (probably with the help of keyup and some 1 or 2 flags ....) not sure, you have to provide some code to get help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to subscribe to `valueChanges` in the [`ngAfterViewInit()`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) method.

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myForm.controls['name'].valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
      console.log(change);
    });
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `valueChanges` would be a correct approach for you.

I assume you are using `setValue` or `patchValue` to set the prefilled values. Both these take as optional `emitEvent` property. If you set it to `false`, it will not fire `valueChanges`. So.... when you set the prefill values, use that:

```
this.form.setValue({ test: "test" }, { emitEvent: false });
```

This action will now not trigger `valueChanges`.

Comment: Actually the values are getting loaded as a default value. Ex. UserName: [someValue, [Validators.Required]

Comment: If that is the case valueChanges will not fire, as form value hasn't changed if it's the **initial values**. You sure you not building the form before? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

all `FormControl` objects have methods such as `markAsUntouched()` or `markAsPristine()` so, in line with what @uminder has indicated, to set the entire form as `pristine` after either the trigger of `ngAfterViewInit` or directly after your form has initialized you could simply traverse all `FormControl` objects and set them as 'pristine'? Any changes thereafter by the user will -by definition- trigger the `valueChanges` of either the form or the control?

below a recursive method for setting all `FormControl` item as `touched` (to trigger validation settings) you can use the same for `control.markAsUntouched` or `control.markAsPristine` ?

```
export function markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup): void {  
  const fa = new FormArray([]).constructor.name;
  Object.values(formGroup.controls).forEach((control: any, i) => {
    if (control.constructor.name === fa) {
      control.controls.forEach((ctrl: any) => markFormGroupTouched(ctrl));
    }    
    else{
      control.markAsTouched();
    }          
  });
}
```

The functions is recursive for `FormArray` so it will traverse the entire form.controls tree.

> NOTE: the `const fa = new FormArray([]).constructor.name;` is to avoid
> problems on minification of your code. Because `typeof FormArray`
> comes back as `FormGroup` you will have to compare on the control
> constructor, but the factory for the `FormArray` gets renamed on
> minification, therefore you cannot hardcode `..=="FormArray"` because that will not be the constructor name when minified. This method allows for that contingency.